# Features in xgboost based on f1 score

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, dataset, accuracy, boosting

Suppose I have a data set with around 3M rows and around 50 columns(features). I have analyzed the data and cleansed it properly as much as possible. When I train this data set on xgboost, a feature map can be plotted with the help of the model which provides the f1 scores for different features in the dataset. Now, if among these 50 features if 10 features have a very low f1 score as compared to the other features, say the f1 scores are in the range of 1-20 for these 10 features, then will dropping these features from my model and training it again improve my accuracy ? And if yes, will the improvement be differentiable?

Comment: This' very much an empirical question and there is no hard and fast rule about it. Why don't you try dropping those features and refit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @horaceT in his comment, it is impossible to know beforehand whether dropping the low importance features will increase or decrease model performance. The good news is that you will get the answer by conducting an experiment where you will drop the low importance features one by one (or all at once) and measure cross-validation performance.

If the dropped features contain redundant information, the performance of the model should stay the same. If the dropped features contain non-redundant and objective-wise relevant information with regard to the kept features, the performance of the model is likely to decrease because you have rather high sample/feature ratio. In case of low sample/feature ratio, dropping those low importance non-redundant features could, however, potentially increase the performance of the model, because of the curse of dimensionality, which states that when the number of features becomes large, the number of training samples required for a good estimator grows exponentially. As you drop features, the complexity of the predictive model decreases, which eases the interpretation of the model, leads to better generalization due to reduced overfitting and lowers training and classification time.

By the way, it is not F1 score that XGBoost is using to assess feature importances. F1 score measures test's accuracy and varies between [0, 1]. XGBoost assess the feature importances with a f(eature)score, which tells the number of occurence of features in the ensemble. If you have for example 100 features but the list of feature importances contains only 75 features, the remaining 25 features never got selected in the trees.